# how to use function from another file in python

Tags: python, import

I made a file containing a scraping function using Python.
I want to import this scraping file from another file and use it, what should I do?

scrap.py

```
def scraper(url):
  list = []
  ...
  return list

def filter(list):
  ...
  return list

def controller(list):
  return filter(scraper(url))
```

another.py

```
import scrap

#scrap.controller('www...')
```

should i change code in scrap.py?
if it is, how to change?

Answer (score 0):

Place two files(`scrap.py`, `another.py`) in the same directory. That's all.

Comment: Stack Overflow is English-only. Please do not post content in non-English languages.